# Set theory question that suppose to relate to graph theory.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let A1,...,Ak be k subsets of the set V={1, ..., n}.
Find a necessary and a sufficient condition for the existance of a representative susbset B,
meaning that for every subset there is a marked representative that belongs to it, a representative can't
represent two subset that he is an element of, but it is possible that a subset has more than one element in the representative subset.

for example: A1={1,2}, A2={2,3},A3={3,4}, A4={1,3}, B={1 (for set A1),2 (for set A2),4 (for set A3),3 (for set A4)}.

I tried to think about hall's thm but I really don't see how it satisfies hall's condition, and how to make that jump from set theory to graph theory to use the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math expressions.

Comment: Apologies, I don't really know how to do that, but I will try to look into it right now sir.

Comment: You should take a look at [Hall’s marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Comment: No apology necessary.  Welcome to MSE.  You'll find you get a much better response when you posts are easy to read.  But you also need to add some signs of effort, or your question will likely be closed.  What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  How far have you gotten?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Will add those right now.

Comment: I tried to look at hall's thm and find common ground but didn't have success in doing so...

Comment: Think about what could take the place of the men and what could take the place of the women in Hall's marriage theorem.